# FPDF Generate blank documennt

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I create pdf in php using FPDF it's always showing blank documents. its size only 1.60kb. i fetching mysql data and want to admit card.
I create pdf in php using FPDF it's always showing blank documents. its size only 1.60kb. i fetching mysql data and want to admit card.

(i) admitcard.php

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#viewapp">View Applications</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="viewapp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <?php
                    $rs1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from demodata");
                    echo '<table class="table table-striped" id="tblData">';
                    echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>ID</th>";
                    echo "<th>NAME</th>";
                    echo "<th>DATE OF BIRTH</th>";
                    echo "<th>EMAIL ID</th>";
                    echo "<th>CONTACT NO.</th>";
                    echo "<th>SIGNUP DATE</th>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
            while($ar = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><a href='viewform.php?id=".$ar[0]."'>" . $ar[0] . "</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $ar[3] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $ar[2] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $ar[4] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $ar[5] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $ar[6] . "</td>";                         
                    echo "<td> <a target='_blank' href='generate_pdf.php?id=".$ar[0]."'>
                         <input type='button' value='PDF' name='adcard' class='toggle btn btn-primary'> </a></td>";                   
                    echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

(ii) genrate_pdf.php

```
<?php
require("fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$a=$_POST["add"];
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$a);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: When do you post your data? And what data do you post? Did you `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you have in?

Comment: Or try to do `$pdf->Cell(40,10,'This page is not blank.');` instead of `$a=$_POST["add"]; $pdf->Cell(40,10,$a);` and see what you get.